# How do I check if the bootloader is unlocked on the LG Volt 2?

Tags: root-access, bootloader, lg

I rooted using kingroot and kingroot is my superuser app.

I want to install clockworkmod to install xposed but I don't know if my bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: You can use apps like Rashr or Flashify to install Recovery from a running Android OS. Need  not to worry about bootloader's status.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into the bootloader should look something like this. [image] In the bottom left it should say if it's locked.
If not you can type in an elevated command promt the command `fastboot oem device-info` that will also let you know

Comment: how do I boot into fastboot mode? The command doesnt work in terminal emulator after using the su command

Comment: Oh this is a weird one but here you go:  Power Off,
Unplug USB,
Hold Volume Up,
Plug in USB